# Wrap the return values with boolean type

Tags: c++, function, image-processing, return-value, return-type

I am trying to write a function with multiple return values. I need to handle the scenario when if there is no image in the path. How can i do this?

I have tried to use map. But it is more for Key, Value pairs is what I think(new to C++).

Below is my code:

```
tuple<Mat, Mat> imageProcessing(boost::filesystem::path pickPath){
    Mat img1, img2;
    // Check if file exists, if not return NULL
    if (!boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(pickPath)) {
        return make_tuple(NULL, NULL); 
    }

        imageFile = imread(pickPath.string());

        // Preprocess code (return 2 mat files)

        return make_tuple(img_1, img_2);
   }



int main(){
    path = "img.jpeg"
    tie(img1, img2) = imageProcessing(path);
}
```

Comment: you can try std::set

Comment: Can you expand your solution? should i have to use in main() or user defined function

Comment: `std::optional` or `boost::optional` or just throw an exception. BTW use of `tuple` in none template code should be discouraged. `tuple` is useful when nothing is known about passed data. In your case use of `struct` with two fields would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) if you want a contiguous collection of objects or use [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) if your function guarantees to return only unique results.

Your method should also handle errors gracefully. In general there are two approaches in C++ for that:

1. Exceptions. When your function encounters bad data/error codes from your 3rd party libraries or any other unexpected scenario you can throw an exception and the function caller needs to write code to handle it. Your method will probably look something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Mat> ProcessImages(const boost:filesystem::path filePath)
{
   if (!boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(pickPath)) {
       throw std::invalid_argument("file does not exist"!); //probably there's a better exception you could throw or you can define your own.
   }
...
```

The caller would look like this:

```cpp
  try{
        auto images = ProcessImage(myFilePath)
  }
  catch(const std::invalid_argument& e ) { 
     // write something to console, log the exception, terminate your process... choose your poison.
  }
```

2. Return an error code. There are several ways of doing this - return a tuple with the first item being the error code and the second the vector, or pass the vector by reference and return only the error code:

```cpp
// if successful the function will return 0.
enum ErrorCode
{
  Successful = 0,
  InvalidArgs = 1,
  ...
}

ErrorCode ProcessImages(const boost:filesystem::path filePath, std::vector<Mat>& outImages)
{
   if (!boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(pickPath)) {
   {
    return InvalidArgs;
   }

   imageFile = imread(pickPath.string());

   outImages.insert(img1);
   outImages.insert(img2);

   return Successful;
}

int main(){
    path = "img.jpeg"
    std::vector<Mat> images;
    auto result = ProcessImages(path, images);
    if (result != Successfull)
    {
      //error
    }
}
```

Comment: Evg, It was one of two options, the implementer should know which one works best. I've updated my code to use std::vector just to keep it more simple.

Comment: @ClaudiuGuiman, it's not about simplicity, it's about semantics. IMO we should use containers judiciously, not just because they can be technically used, but according to the semantics they imply. `std::set` holds unique comparable elements in sorted order. This is the semantics you convey to the reader of your code when you use `std::set`. If you don't actually need this semantics, `std::set` is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `vector<Mat>` and push all images to this vector and return it. Then you can check the length of this vector after you call the function. If it's zero, that means you didn't push anything(if there's no file found in the path). Otherwise, extract all the images from the vector as you want.